# Spring Security apply filters to insecured URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have Spring Security configured to ignore certain URL's (`/session/**`, `/v2/api-docs/**`) as below but it still tries to authenticate them. `TokenAuthenticationFilter` is an implementation of `TokenAuthenticationFilter` which would check for bearer token.

Could any one please help to see why Spring Security is not excluding/ignoring the mentioned URLs? The Spring Security configuration file is below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)  
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/session/**"),new AntPathRequestMatcher("/v2/api-docs/**")
    );

    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

    SecurityTokenAuthenticationProvider provider;

    AppSecurityConfig(final SecurityTokenAuthenticationProvider provider) {
        super(true);
        this.provider = requireNonNull(provider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
                .and()
            .authenticationProvider(provider)
            .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/session/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .logout().disable();
    }

    TokenAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        final SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
        return successHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(FORBIDDEN);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Just replace web.ignoring().requestMatchers() to web.ignoring().antMatchers()

Comment: Tried  with web.ignoring().antMatchers("/session/**").antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**");  but it still doesnt exclude the urls

Comment: I'm just bit confused how you determine your PUBLIC_URL, and wanted sure what you write your antMatcher in right way.
 Ok, if so then try add @EnableWebSecurity annotation to your configuration class, i think it should resolve your problem.

Comment: I have all those annotation in place. It still doesn't work

Comment: The security rules are performed as declared, if you need skip white list rules (`.antMatchers`) need declare before `.addFilterBefore` in `protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http)` method.

Comment: @user9883158 Do you use Spring Boot?

Comment: It doesn't use spring boot

Comment: I tried adding the .antmatchers() before the .addFilterBefore() but it still it doesnt seem to ignore the url. The following is the order of the  security filter that is being applied:-                                                                        Security filter chain: [
  TokenAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]